# Xvfb - RHEL 5.4

Tags: buffer, virtual, xvfb, rhel5

I am trying to initialize a display using Xvfb and am running into this error. Can you help me resolve this error?

```
-bash-3.2$ Xvfb :001 -ac
_XSERVTransSocketOpenCOTSServer: Unable to open socket for inet6
_XSERVTransOpen: transport open failed for inet6/hostname:1
_XSERVTransMakeAllCOTSServerListeners: failed to open listener for inet6
_XSERVTransmkdir: Owner of /tmp/.X11-unix should be set to root
Could not init font path element unix/:7100, removing from list!
```

Comment: Also post the code snippets for which you getting this error.

Comment: This fixed it:- "Xvfb :001 -nolisten tcp &"

Comment: @Balaji You can answer your own question